# How to show composable on top of its own running application?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation, android-motionlayout

I am trying to minimize a composable with motion layout and show it on top of previous composable (the same running app). I could only get to the part of minimizing it right now but the parent composition also needs resizing for sure along with showing this on top of currently running application. Maybe this is a two part question that I am trying to solve.

1. Adjust the parent composable size based off its children dynamically.
2. Show this composable on top of the currently running application.

```
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateFloatAsState
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintSet
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ExperimentalMotionApi
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.MotionLayout
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.MotionLayoutDebugFlags
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.layoutId
import java.util.EnumSet

@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class)
@Composable
fun TestMobilePlayerScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var animate by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val progress by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = if (animate) 1f else 0f, animationSpec = tween(1_000))

    MotionLayout(
        start = ConstraintSet(
            """
            {
              videoPlayer: {
                width: "spread",
                height: "16:9",
                top: ['parent', 'top'],
                start: ['parent', 'start'],
                end: ['parent', 'end']
              },
              programDetails: {
                width: "spread",
                height: "spread",
                top: ['videoPlayer', 'bottom'],
                bottom: ['parent', 'bottom'],
                start: ['videoPlayer', 'start'],
                end: ['videoPlayer', 'end']
              }
            }"""
        ),
        end = ConstraintSet(
            """
            {
              videoPlayer: {
                width: 200,
                height: "16:9",
                bottom: ['parent', 'bottom', 16],
                end: ['parent', 'end', 16],
              },
              programDetails: {
                width: 200,
                height: 0,
                top: ['videoPlayer', 'bottom'],
                start: ['videoPlayer', 'start'],
                end: ['videoPlayer', 'end']
              }
            }"""
        ),
        progress = progress,
        debug = EnumSet.of(MotionLayoutDebugFlags.SHOW_ALL),
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Transparent),
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId("videoPlayer")
                .background(color = Color.Black)
                .clickable { animate = !animate }
        )
        Column(
            Modifier
                .layoutId("programDetails")
                .background(color = Color.Green)
        ) {
        }
    }
}
```

Start State:
[image: When we first open this composable]

Mid State:
[image: The composable mid transition to end state]

Final State:
[image: Final state of composable]

Comment: yes, its a similar feature as Picture-In-Picture. But this is a different requirement to show PIP like composition on top of the running application.

Comment: Sir you don't need to exit the app to invoke PiP. You can have one window within your app as well, just read the docs.